# Proper way to escape json data in PHP without using JS comment hack

Tags: javascript, php, json, security, xss

Consider the code below to send a json string to js from php,

```
<?php
    $str = "<!--<script>"; // This is from user input
?>

<script>
   var json_str = <?= json_encode($str) ?>;
</script>
```

The string will break the HTML, and the way to solve it is via something like the old school comment hack, e.g.

```
<script>
<!--
   var json_str = <?= json_encode($str) ?>;
//-->
</script>
```

Are there any alternative?

Comment: The example shown will not result the expected way, anyway, if you need to escape it, you can use htmlentities

Comment: `var str = <?= json_encode(strip_tags($str)); ?>;` not an option? [`strip_tags`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), or even a simple `str_replace(array('<!--', '-->`), '', $str)` should do

Comment: @RoyalBg: Read the question: the OP is aware of the problem

Answer (score 5):

You can use the flag `JSON_HEX_TAG`, so that `<` and `>` will be encoded as `\u003C` and `\u003E` respectively.

```
json_encode($str, JSON_HEX_TAG)
```

Comment: +1 This is the best way - as per the [OWASP XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Output_Encoding_Rules_Summary) - `Except for alphanumeric characters, escape all characters with the \uXXXX unicode escaping format (X = Integer).`.